# How to force GCC to pass 128bits/256bits struct as function param in xmm/ymm register?

Tags: gcc, struct, 64-bit, parameter-passing, avx

How to force GCC to pass 128bits/256bits struct as function param in xmm/ymm register?
ie. if my struct is 256bits wide (UnsignedLongLongStruct below)

(I know if I use intrinsics to make a packed integer, gcc is smart enough to put it into %ymm register, but can I do it with struct ?)

```
typedef struct {
   unsigned long long ull1;
   unsigned long long ull2;
   unsigned long long ull3;
   unsigned long long ull4;
} UnsignedLongLongStruct;

void func1( UnsignedLongLongStruct unsignedLongLongStruct ) {
....
}
```

Comment: First align with the previous century and use C++!

Comment: Are you sure that's a good idea?  If the function needs the values as separate scalars, getting them into a ymm reg in the caller and out again in the callee is going to be more expensive than passing them the normal way, even if that means they have to go on the stack because all the available arg-passing registers are used.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: It seems the calling conventions explicitly mention __m256 and friends to be placed in the umm regs.

In [X86-64 System V ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf), point 3.2.3, you can check how parameters are passed. My reading is that only `__m256` arguments will be turned into one SSE and 3 SSEUP 8-byte chunks, which allows them to be passed in a ymm register.

This will make it so that your argument gets passed in memory, which is what we see in clang, gcc, and icc: [Test program on godbolt](http://goo.gl/eGbg3V)

In order to pass it as a register, as I read the calling conventions, it seem that you have to pass it as a __m256 (or a variant of it).

Answer (score 0):

The calling conventions are a bit of a mess across different platforms and compilers. You should pass the input to your function by value as an `__m256`.

If it's a trivial function and you want to ensure GCC inlines it, you could declare it with the `always_inline` attribute to avoid any unnecessary loads/stores:

```
inline __attribute__((always_inline)) __m256 foo(__m256 const input);
```

Comment: If you use `always_inline`, there's no point messing with `__m256i`; just pass the struct.  The code that's inlined will use it in the most efficient way the compiler can come up with.